# Overriding image version in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working on overriding default `docker-compose.yml` file using `docker-compose.override.yml` as shown in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/), And I can able to specify `ports` and `volumes` in the override file.

In the similar way, is it also possible to specify version of the image which needs to be deployed? If no, what is the best way to handle such circumstance where we need to specify different version for the image?

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Docker is already having that feature. I tried to override image name with simple docker-compose, it is working.

For example,

`docker-compose.yml` with content,

```
my-httpd:
  image: httpd:latest
  ports:
    - "1110:80"
```

And `docker-compose.override.yml` with content,

```
my-httpd:
  image: httpd:2.4
```

After the execution of `docker-compose -d`, here is the docker ps info,

[image]

It uses `ports` from `docker-compose.yml` (not overrided) and `image` from `docker-compose.override.yml` as it is getting overridden here.

**Note**: It you have different names and location, you could use it like the following command instead of `docker-compose -d`,

```
docker-compose -f <DOCKER COMPOSE LOCATION> -f <OVERRIDE FILE LOCATION> up -d
```

**Edit 2:**

Overriding in the above manner will only replace the non array values and the array variables will be merged.

For example, if I have `ports` in both files which is an array, it will bind both the ports instead of taking ports value just from the overriding file unlike the `image` part (non array).

Answer (score 10):

There is (now?) a better option for what you want to do.  From
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

It’s possible to use environment variables in your shell to populate values inside a Compose file:

```
web:
  image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

Answer (score -2):

For example you need to have 3 versions of docker:

- docker-composer-master.yml
- docker-composer-dev.yml
- docker-composer-docker.yml

You can create 3 file docker-composer and add content as the below picture

[image]